# Dictionary.toArray: Unable to convert dictionary to array, key 'NDVI' has a null value

Tags: geometry, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am trying to reduce a region by clipping an image from copernicus to get NDVI and then calculate a Kc value. However, Once I use a polygon I imported with the "Draw a Shape" tool, the calculations cannot be performed. I get the same error for all.

```
Dictionary.toArray: Unable to convert dictionary to array, key 'NDVI' has a null value
```

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening?

These are the sources I have in my script:
[image]

This is the actual script:

```js
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20170519T173911_20170519T174800_T13RBM');
var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
var NDVI_LI = NDVI.clip(Lixin);
var image=image.addBands(NDVI);

var maxNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: Lixin,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var minNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: Lixin,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var meanNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: Lixin,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

meanNDVI = meanNDVI.toArray();
minNDVI = minNDVI.toArray();
maxNDVI = maxNDVI.toArray();
print('maxNDVI',maxNDVI);
print('minNDVI',minNDVI);
print('meanNDVI',meanNDVI);

var  Kc = ((NDVI_LI.subtract(minNDVI)).divide((maxNDVI).subtract(minNDVI))).multiply(1.20);
var Kc = Kc.arrayGet([0]);
var image = image.add(Kc);
Map.centerObject(Lixin,15);
```

And these are the errors I'm getting in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reduceRegion** function returns a dictionary object and not a numeric value. The problem with the code is that you are using the dictionaries to add and multiply, not the values contained in them. It can be fixed by extracting those values to the minNDVI, meanNDVI and maxNDVI objects and converting them to **ee.Number** objects.

For example,

```
var meanNDVI = ee.Number(NDVI.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: Lixin,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}).get('NDVI'));
```

This way you won't have to convert them to arrays either.

You can see a working version of the script [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/86ffe2d9af1b320c3d8c8e5ebe7e55a1). Although, i did create my own geometry but yours should work the same way.

Comment: Thank you. This worked well.